# keep express app running on Linux cloud server

Tags: node.js, linux, mongodb, express, ubuntu-14.04

I am pretty new to node/express. In the past I've used Django and apache. Recently I developed an express app and it works great when I manually run it and test it. I've done research on how to keep a node app with mongo db up and running after logging out of the linux server and there seems to be a lot of different answers. Is there a single ideal agreed upon way of doing it?

Comment: You can try them out yourself, or see which one's documentation is easier to follow or which one the securest or which one has more active community.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1):

You can use tools like [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) to keep node process running

Comment: Or [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever).